# How to move a rotated view in the right direction on Android?

Tags: android, animation, view, rotation

I have a View I rotate programmatically by a random degree with

```
view.setRotation(rnd.nextInt(181));
```

How can I now move the view in the direction of the rotation? If I use

```
view.animate().translationXBy...
```

the view will move to the left or right. Is there a way to combine translationX and translationY to have the view move exactly in the direction of the rotation? Or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself with Pythagoras:

```
float rotation = view.getRotation();
float translationX = (float)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation)) * distance);
float translationY = (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation)) * distance);
view.animate().translationXBy(translationX).translationYBy(translationY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tween animation set of rotate and translate animation by method of view setAnimation()
for example:

```
    RotateAnimation animation=new RotateAnimation(0, 360);
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    textView.setAnimation(animation);
    animation.start();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. This code creates a rotation animation from 0 to 360 degrees. If I rotate while moving the view, it will still move in the wrong direction and rotate while doing that. That's not what I want to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: you have to create animation set of rotate and translate animation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(false);
set.addAnimation(new RotateAnimation(0, 360));
set.addAnimation(new TranslateAnimation(10, 100, 10, 100));